# Visual Studio remote debugging (ssh) on linux OS (buildroot)?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio

I'm trying to attach Visual Studio 2019 to a linux machine (64-bit Intel) running a custom Buildroot OS. When I try to connect via ssh with a password I get the error:

"Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named user@ip.address. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80004005."

This is what happens right after I enter my credentials in the Attach to Process screen. That is before I even see the list of processes to attach to.

If I point VS to a different Linux machine (Ubuntu) it immediately shows me a list of processes running on it.

Any idea what I'm missing? Buildroot's sshd server says: `OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017` and I do have `wget` installed. I installed `curl` in case that was it, but it still didn't work.

My Buildroot system is not on the public internet, but I'm not sure that matters. I'm guessing/hoping there's a secret requirement that I'm missing and can't find via google. Anyone have any ideas to try?

Comment: Were you able to figure out the solution I am also stuck on this error.

Comment: I have also the same issue with Toradex Linux minimal image (uses lightweight software packages like busybox, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your OS image has a minimalistic “ps” command which accepts no argument, I think the problem comes from there : maybe VS runs a “ps” with several arguments (e.g. aux) to get the process list but the ps returns an error.

Update: even if you change the "ps" command to a more complete one, you can see the list of processes but you still can't attach to a process. VS apparently uses other commands that don't exist under a minimalist Linux distribution for embedded.